# Running self host server on Ubuntu, can't increase upload limit past 2MB, tried all the solutions

Tags: php

https://atlantisthemes.com/fix-upload_max_filesize/ 
None of the above solutions worked for me. I have a high end theme waiting to be uploaded please help thank you very much. For the record I installed lamp on ubuntu. self hosted server. no solution as of yet. sincerely

Comment: use `phpinfo()` to find out which `php.ini` is used.

Comment: Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2018/02. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Comment: Check your permissions. Did you work as root? Make sure your uploads directories are writable by the user running PHP, often `www-data`.

Comment: yes i am working as root, very new to this, where do i grant permission? i am trying to upload a highend theme onto wordpress lamp ubuntu self host

Comment: thanks i got it now, new problem, ftp credentials how do i get that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your server? If yes: 
You can change your php.ini file with your terminal like. (check your php version first with phpinfo() to find out which php.ini)

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

The default lines that control the file size upload are:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Change this default value to your desired maximum file upload size. For example, if you needed to upload a 30MB file you would change these lines to:

```
upload_max_filesize = 30M
```

When you have the php.ini file configured for your needs, save the changes, and exit the text editor.

Restart the web server to enable the changes. For Apache on Ubuntu 14.04, this command will restart the web server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```